# ModSecurity Action Azure API Management

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-api-management

I have a Web API deployed in Azure and expose via API management. I have another API that calls that API. The problem now is that, when we try to post a data with special character. API management is blocking the request.

I understand that there are firewall rules implemented in Azure API that causes API management to blocked the request. I also don't want to disable those rules but my API should know that those strings are valid. I am planning to encode those especial character but is there a best way to do this other than encoding special characters?

Comment: APIM doesn't put any rules on API or payload by default. If there is anything - that must be added by customer explicitly through policies. Did you try to make test call through Azure portal to trace it and see where exactly it fails?

Comment: if we pass a field with special character we hit this rule
942400 - 942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI